# Indy10 TCP and asynchronous data exchange

Tags: delphi, tcpclient, indy, tcpserver

Good morning to all.I am building a Delphi TCP server/client application using Indy 10.0.52,with TIdTCPClient and TIdTCPServer. I have problem with receiving asynchronous responses from server. Here's my part of sample code:

Client:

```
procedure TfrmMain.ClientSend();
begin
   tcpClient.IOHandler.WriteLn('100|HelloServer');  
   if tcpClient.IOHandler.ReadLn() = '1100' then //Here I get 1100
      begin
         tcpClient.IOHandler.WriteLn('200|Are_you_ready_for_data?');
         if tcpClient.IOHandler.ReadLn() = '1200' then
            begin
            end;
      end;
end;
```

Server:

```
procedure TfrmMain.tcpServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var command:Integer;
var received,value:String;
begin
   received := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
   command := StrToInt(SomeSplitFunction(received,'first_part')); //Here I get 100
   value := SomeSplitFunction(received,'second_part'); //Here I get 'HelloServer'

   case command of
      100:begin
         //Do something with value...    
         AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('1100');    
      end;
      200:begin
         //Do something with value...    
         AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('1200');
      end;
   end;
end;
```

The problem is that the case 200 on tcpServerExecute is never executed, therefore the second ReadLn on client site is never read.Is multiple asynchronous data sending in single procedure supported?I have came across several examples with simple Indy TCP Server/Client applications, but I'm little stuck here.Just to mention that connection is working and I connect to server without problems.

Comment: You are not doing any asynchronous sending. OnExecute is called in a loop for the lifetime of the connection. You are doing a ReadLn, followed by a WriteLn, followed by a ReadLn, followed by a WriteLn, in sequential order.

Comment: Is this your real copy/pasted client code? It is writing to `tcpClient` but reading from `tcpKlijent` for the `1100` reply.

Comment: BTW, 10.0.52 is very old. The current version is 10.6.0.

Comment: I didn't copy/pasted, in my code is indeed tcpClient(I made a typo), I edited the question so that's not a problem. Can you explain me little more about asynchronous sending or point me to some sample?

Comment: The code you showed works just fine when I test it.  Both commands execute as expected. So it has to be a problem in your real code that you did not show.

Comment: Ok, here's my complete code, http://pastebin.com/y236giQf .You will notice that I have added mmoClient.Lines.Add(value); on lines 98 and 103, and with that my application freezes.

Comment: The `OnExecute` event is triggered in the context of a worker thread, not the main thread. Directly accessing UI components from outside of the main thread is dangerous. Deadlocks are just one of many different side effects that can occur. You **must** synchronize with the main thread in order to access your `TMemo` safely. You can use Indy's own `TIdSync` or `TIdNotify` class for that, or any other inter-thread synchronization mechanism you are comfortable with, as long as the target code that accesses the UI is executed in the context of the main thread, not a worker thread.